# Horizontal scroll not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm working on this portfolio website for a guy who makes architecture models. For the gallery I used a ready-made code for a horizontal scroll. The code seems to work as expected in Safari and Firefox, but in Chrome I get this strange error involving the track pad scroll.

Here's the page:
http://www.modellverkstaden.com/modeller.html

When scrolling with the track pad in Chrome, the scroll automatically snaps back to the beginning. So the scroll is impossible to use. However, it works perfectly using an "external mouse". I also get an error with the menu button in the top. The right border of the button disappears, only in Chrome.

Would really appreciate some help in what this may have to do with and how I should proceed to make it work in Chrome and other browsers.

Here's the html for the specific gallery page I'm having trouble with:

```
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">


<meta name="description" content="Modellverkstaden">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="center.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
    .section { 
        display: block; 
        width: auto; 
        height: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        float: left; 
        margin-left: 20px; 
    }

    .section img {
        height: 100%;

        position: relative;
    }

    p {margin-top: 1em;}

    #content {
        display: none!important;
        padding-top: 6.3em!important;
    }

    img {
        height: auto;
    }

    img.logo {
        height: inherit;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { 

 #content {
  display: block!important;
 }

 img {
 width: 100%;
 }

 img.logo {
 width: inherit;
 }
 #top {
 position: fixed;
 }
}
</style>

<script src="Demo%20-%20Horizontal%20Scrolling-filer/jquery_002.js"></script>
<script src="Demo%20-%20Horizontal%20Scrolling-filer/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>

<!-- Enable HTML5 for old browsers -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<title>Modellverkstaden > Modeller</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>

<div id="hamburger"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('mob-menu');"><img src="pics/menu.png" /></a></div>

<div id="top" style="position: fixed!important;">
<ul>
    <li style="border: none;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;margin-right:  2em;">
        <label><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="pics/logo.png"></a>    </label>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="om.html">Om</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="uppdragsgivare.html">Uppdragsgivare</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu" id="active">
        <a href="modeller.html">Modeller</a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="mob-menu"><ul><li><a href="om.html">Om</a></li><li><a     href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li><li><a     href="uppdragsgivare.html">Uppdragsgivare</a></li><li><a     href="modeller.html">Modeller</a></li></ul></div>

<div id="content">
<h1>Modeller</h1>
<div id="images">

    <img src="pics/IMAG1306.jpg"><p></p>

    <img src="pics/blandat-055.jpg"><p></p>
    <img src="pics/blandat-069.jpg">

    <img src="pics/IMAG0237.jpg"><p></p>
    <img src="pics/IMAG1263.jpg"><p></p>


    <img src="pics/diverse-paris-och-Csh-21-371.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_1464.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_1442.jpg"><p> </p>

    <img src="pics/IMG_1477.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_9043.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_9067.jpg">
    <img src="pics/IMG_9071.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_9161.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_9201.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/IMG_9658.jpg"><p> </p>
            <img src="pics/IMG_9692.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/juni-10-181.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/juni-10-198.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/Kajen-4-JM-2012-B3.jpg"><p> </p>
            <img src="pics/modellv-ffs-016.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(1-of-12).jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(2-of-12).jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(7-of-12).jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-002.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-009.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-023.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/titti,barnen-mm20061028-073.jpg"><p> </p>
    <img src="pics/B19219_012.jpg"><p></p>
    <img src="pics/B19219_017.jpg">
    <img src="pics/B19219_023.jpg">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="filler"></div>



<div id="container">
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMAG1306.jpg"><p></p></div>

    <div class="section"><img src="pics/blandat-055.jpg"><p></p></div>
    <div class="section"><img src="pics/blandat-069.jpg"></div>

    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMAG0237.jpg"><p></p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMAG1263.jpg"><p></p></div>


    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/diverse-paris-och-Csh-21-371.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_1464.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_1442.jpg"><p> </p></div>

    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_1477.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9043.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9067.jpg"></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9071.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9161.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9201.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9658.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/IMG_9692.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/juni-10-181.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/juni-10-198.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/Kajen-4-JM-2012-B3.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/modellv-ffs-016.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(1-of-12).jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(2-of-12).jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/modellverkstaden2-(7-of-12).jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-002.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-009.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/Pinc-House-Blackbarn-Sport-Pacific-1.50-023.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section yellow"><img src="pics/titti,barnen-mm20061028-073.jpg"><p> </p></div>
    <div class="section"><img src="pics/B19219_012.jpg"><p></p></div>
    <div class="section"><img src="pics/B19219_017.jpg"></div>
    <div class="section"><img src="pics/B19219_023.jpg"></div>
    <div class="section"><a style="position: absolute;z-index: 1000;" href="modeller.html"><p>← Tillbaka</p></a></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>





</body></html>
```

And here's the CSS for the elements involved in the horizontal scroll section:

```
#filler { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 18750px; height: 100%; }
 #container { width: 18750px; position: absolute; top: 40%; margin-top: -150px;margin-left: 12px; }
.section { 
        display: block; 
        width: auto; 
        height: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        float: left; 
        margin-left: 20px; 
    }

    .section img {
        height: 100%;

        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: You should provide some code, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Added the relevant code in the original post. You can also visit the URL and see the source code from there.

Comment: what is this for - `$('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1);
            e.preventDefault();
        });`

Comment: It would be a lot easier to pinpoint the error if you provided a [mcve] of your problem, either as snippet here or in a jsFiddle. Could you add all your assets and make it work?

Comment: I deleted the code that @SoorajChandran asked about. After deleting that code the track pad scroll in Chrome works. But instead, when using the scroll wheel on a mouse, it doesn't work at all. So the script seems to translate vertical scrolling into horizontal scrolling and Chrome seems to not be able to read that script entirely.

Is there anything I must change in the script in order to make it work in Chrome?